# Spring Boot Async pass some data to a server, wait for response as file

Tags: java, spring-boot, http

I'm using Spring Boot 2 with `io` and `nio` to create an asynchronous call to a server which then returns a file. For this set-up I've created a simple server which takes some html input and then returns a pdf.

My issue lies with passing the data, in this example some simple html, to the server that generates the pdf output. How do I best create a POST request using Spring Boot? Should I use POST for this in the first place?

The code below works for getting and passing along a pdf from the server.

What it does:

1. Create the inputstream that will receive the data
2. Create the outputstream that will write to a tempfile
3. Open the connection and stream to the tempfile until it's done

Code:

```
@Async
private File getPdf(String html) {
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    File pdf = null;
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    int byteContent;        
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:3000/html2pdf");
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        File directory = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        pdf = File.createTempFile("test", ".pdf", directory);           
        outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(pdf.getPath()));
        while ((byteContent = inputStream.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(data, 0, byteContent);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return pdf;
}
```

Any other ideas on how to make this code better are very welcome too!

Comment: I think you need to return a Future<File>

Comment: If you use Async, you will not be able to capture the returned file by get pdf method as the call flow will not wait there.
I think you are looking for completableFuture 
 https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, but it works with an `@Async` call in a thread that uses a `DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>>` to delay returning output right away. I can now generate a huge pdf which takes about 5 minutes and still return it just fine. I'll clean up a bit and post an example.